# $().trigger working from console but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've a html template that modifies the look and feel of a html select box.

```
 <select id='floorinput' class='select multiple-as-single easy-multiple-selection check-list allow-empty' multiple style="width:100px"></select>
```

The template uses classes to beautify the select box.
The options of select box are being populated by the result of an ajax call, and is working correctly.
The select box finally renders on browser like this:

```
<span class="select multiple-as-single easy-multiple-selection check-list allow-empty replacement" style="width: 97px; " tabindex="0">
    <span class="select-value alt">All</span>
    <span class="select-arrow"></span>
    <span class="drop-down custom-scroll" style="">
    <span class="selected"><span class="check"></span>Floor-1</span>
    <span class="selected"><span class="check"></span>Floor-2</span>
    .....
    <div class="custom-vscrollbar" style="display: none; ">
       <div></div>
    </div></span>
    <select id="floorinput" class="" multiple="" style="width: 100px; display: none; " tabindex="-1">
       <option value="Floor-1" selected="selected">Floor-1</option>
       <option value="Floor-2" selected="selected">Floor-2</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

The template works by hiding the actual select box and rendering a fancy selectbox instead.

I want to simulate mouse clicks on this select box. The purpose is to deselect the options that are already selected.
The template code cannot handle the programmatic clicks on options of #floorInput (the actual html input).
So I decided to click the spans like:

```
var j = 0;
//DEselect selected floors programtically
$("#floorinput option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("selected") == "selected") {
        console.log('should deselect this:' + $(this).text());
        $('.select-value.alt').click();//simulate click to open dropdown
        $('.drop-down.custom-scroll span.check')[j].click();//perform click. ERROR here
    }
    else {
        console.log('already selected :' + $(this).text());
    }
    j++;
});
```

I am using chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m on Windows 7.
The code throws an error like :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined
```

But it works as expected when I call the same methods through Chrome's console:

```
$('.select-value.alt').click();
$('.drop-down.custom-scroll span.check')[0].click();//select or deselect first option
```

Possible cause of the problem may be the markup of select box is not available immediately after the call of  $('.select-value.alt').click();
But I've tried delaying the second method call by several methods and it doesnt work.

Any scenario where jquery methods are working through console but not during actual execution?
Please help.
PS:The spam prevention is not letting me upload the screenshot :(.

Comment: yes. its all setup.
i use $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: Moreover:
$('.drop-down.custom-scroll span.check').click(); is working perfectly fine.
it selects/deselects all the options at once.
But I want to select or deselect selectively(clicking some not all the options)

Comment: I think you should use `$(whatever).prop("selected")` instead of checking the attribute value with `.attr()`.

Comment: Have you tried using http://code.google.com/p/expandselect/ to expand the select option programmatically by simulating a mouse click?

Comment: yes gunjan sir. i've tried both expandselect and my own code to simulate a click on underlying select. but the problem is that this template doesnt have two-way wiring with the underlying select box. Means, actions performed on proxy selectbox will be relayed to the actual selectbox but not the other way round. :(

btw, many thanks for looking into the matter.